# cron jobs under mac os 10.6 snow leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, cron

I'm trying to set up an automated svn commit to run semi-hourly under mac os 10.6, but the crontabs i'm adding to cron don't seem to be valid and/or don't seem to even be looked at by cron. For testing i made a simple crontab and script:

Crontab: 

`*/2 *   *   *   *   /Users/username/crontest`

where username is replaced with my system username, thus pointing to my home directory (and yes, those really are tabs between each value - they aren't faithfully reproduced in the `code` section)

I'm running a `crontab -r` first, then running `crontab .mycrontab` that contains the above line.  `crontab -l` spits out the line above, and running `ps -A | grep cron` shows `/usr/sbin/cron` running, which I assume is the cron daemon under mac os x.  The `/Users/username/crontest` script is simply appending a line of text to a text file, as such:

`echo "hi" >> /Users/username/crontest.txt`

What gives?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oops...I was missing the newline character at the end of the cron job.  That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Just to be clear,  I had a similar problem and adding an extra new line to my file when running contrab -e fixed it.

Ick.

Answer (score 5):

Although the preferred method on OS X for running automated jobs is [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html), `cron` is still supported.  Chances are you have a permissions problems with your script; make sure it has execute permission.

Also, `*/2` means every two minutes, not semi-hourly.  Try setting the minutes field with a list of minutes:

```
0,30    *   *   *   *   /Users/username/crontest
```

Works for me on 10.6.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Side note: I guess I didn't clarify in my original question that, even though my final cron job was intended to run semi-hourly, my test cron job was in fact intended to run once every two minutes.